# how to instantiate a template of template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a bit confused at the concept of "template of template". For example, this can compile:

```
template<typename X1>
class T1 {};

template<class X2, template<typename X> class T >
class TT {};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TT<int, T1> tt1; //compile ok
    //TT<int, T1<int>> tt2; //compile error 
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused here that, `tt1` definition is supplying `int` for type parameter `X2`, and `T1` for template type parameter `T`, these are all fine... but `T1` itself need a type `X1`, without this provided, how could C++ compiler compile?

Comment: `template<typename X> class T` - The `X` here is a red herring, I'd say.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't understand -- `T` is a template that requires a type parameter `X` to specify it, isn't so?

Comment: Not quite. It accepts one argument. But there is absolutely no use for `X` in there.

Comment: Could you please use `main` instead of `_tmain` in your exemplary code? I think that, since the problem you are facing is not OS specific, so your snippet should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to differentiate between a class template and a class template instantiation. An instantiation is an actual type, while the template itself is *not a type*, it's more a name for a family of types.

The parameter `T` is supposed to be a template, a family of types to say colloquially. And for `tt1` you do supply that in the form of `T1`.

But in the failed attempt, you don't supply a template, you supply a type (by instantiating `T1`). `T1<int>` is not a template, but some class.

I guess what throws you off is the fact you named the parameter of `T` (`X`). The name you supply is not at all material to the declaration of `TT`. It expects a template as its second parameter, not a template and its argument. As a matter of fact, there is no `X` for `TT` to refer to. You can try, and the compiler will complain it has no idea what `X` is.